# problema ao tentar ocultar o Navbar depois que um item foi clicado (bootstrap 5 react)

Tags: javascript, react, nav-bar

Estou tentando ocultar a barra de navegação depois que um item for clicado (bootstrap 5 react), mas depois de colocar `data-bs-toggle = "collapse"` e `data-bs-target = ". Navbar-collapse.show"` o `Navlink` do react router não funciona.

Já procurei em vários lugares e não consigo fazer funcionar.

Este é o código.

```
import React from 'react';
import "./Navbar.css";
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


const Navbar = () => {
    
    return (

<nav className="navbar fixed-top navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark" id="telaprincipal">
  <div className="container-fluid">
    
    <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/home" activeClassName="active"><i class="fas fa-calculator" ></i></NavLink>
    
    <NavLink className="navbar-brand" to="/home" activeClassName="active">HOME</NavLink>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLin" role="button" 
          data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Informações
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLin">
          <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLin" role="button" 
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Calculos  <i 
                class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <NavLink data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show" className="dropdown-item" to="/primeiro" activeClassName="active">Cálculo 1</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show" className="dropdown-item" to="/segundo" activeClassName="active">Cálculo 2</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show" className="dropdown-item" to="/terceiro" activeClassName="active">Cálculo 3</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show" className="dropdown-item" to="/quarto" activeClassName="active">Cálculo 4</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show" className="dropdown-item" to="/quinto" activeClassName="active">Cálculo 5</NavLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>         
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/conversor" activeClassName="active">Conversor de Unidades</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/fale" activeClassName="active">Fale conosco</NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito a função disso, mas acho usar o [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) pode ajudar. Você pode usar o `<Nav.Link />` do bootstrap com a propriedade [`as={NavLink}`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction#as-prop-api) para ter um NavLink do router estilizado com bootstrap.